# How do I open then activate a document

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

My VBA is no longer supporting the code that was working before.

When I tried `Objword.Documents.Open` and then `docword.Activate`, the document is opened but I get

> 4248 Run time error, "the command is not available because no document is open".

VBA macro references has the MS Office 16 Object Library selected.

```vb
ObjWord.Visible= True
Dim docword As object
Dim OCC as ContentControl

ObjWord.Activate

Set docWord = objWord.Documents.Open( Filename)
docWord.Activate-------Error
For each oCC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    Select  Case Occ.Title
        Case abc
            Occ.Range.Text
```

Comment: I/O operations (save, open, copy, paste) typically run more slowly than your code. The Activate command can't run, because it fired before the document was actually opened. Search for ways to pause your code with search terms like _"word" VBA sleep doevents_

Comment: Could you show us the code that your are executing and explain how it is triggered? What is `objWord`? Do you open a new instance of Word?

Comment: Would really help to show more code, to put the error in context.

Comment: I have made edits to the question to include the code.

Comment: `doc.Word.Activate` looks like a typo.  Your document variable is named `docWord`.  If this is not your *exact code* then please copy/paste the exact code from the VBA editor.  "This is sort of my code" is not very useful for debugging.  Does the document you're opening contain any auto-run macros?  Are you creating a new instance of Word to open the document - if Yes why do that?

Comment: Sorry about that, it was docWord.Activate only. I am opening up a template and making edits to that, the only way I can do that is by opening a document, updating it and saving it as a new file.

Comment: Can you please check and let me know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have set a variable for the document you have opened you should not be using `ActiveDocument`. Your code should run regardless of whether the newly opened document is activated.

So, assuming your code is not being run from Word it should be:

```
ObjWord.Visible= True
Dim docWord As Document
Dim OCC as ContentControl

ObjWord.Activate

Set docWord = objWord.Documents.Open(Filename)
For each oCC In docWord.ContentControls
 
  Select  Case Occ.Title
    Case abc
     Occ.Range.Text
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me resolve the issue.